# Which Minimum Spanning tree algorithm to use in which situation

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, graph-algorithm

I am newbie to Minimum spanning trees and trying to figure out which MST algorithm to use in any particular situation. Can anybody provide some examples with any particular situation where one of the MST algorithm is more suitable than others

Comment: What algorithms do you consider? Those listed on Wikipedia? Borůvka and Kruskal only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [pdf](http://www.aka.fi/Tiedostot/Tiedostot/Viksu/Viksu%202008/IgorPodsechin.pdf)

Quick Summery (quoting the page):

"Boruvka’s and Kruskal’s algorithms are clearly
more useful if applied to the real world, while Prim’s runtime grows far too quickly with the order
of the graph to be of use in a serial processing environment."

"Out of the three algorithms, Boruvka’s holds most promise when parallel computing is considered.
It is parallelizable by design and involves searching locally for the smallest edge and then
combining the resulting trees after each step. Division of tasks between multiple computer
processing nodes would be the logical extension of Boruvka’s algorithm. However, as can be seen
from this paper, Kruskal’s algorithm is much more efficient in a serial environment."

Comment: Kruskal and Prim have same complexity. I would challenge the first statement you give here.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know enough about MST to argue this. I merely found the article and wanted to share.

Comment: @izomorphius The big-oh notation neglects constants. It doesn't matter an algorithm starts wiinning at 10k nodes if you'll ever get to 800 nodes at most.

Comment: @JanDvorak surely. However I have compared both algorithms numerous times and believe that if you implement them well they do not differ significantly.

Comment: One more situation pls consider this also....Dijakstra's algo which works for single source shortest path is also creating one MST out of many MST's ...this can be used also to find MST's

Comment: @izomorphius: Kruskal and Prim have the same asymptotic complexity if you also ignore the constant factor.  Kruskal's often faster in practice because the slow step is a sort, while Prim needs a linear number of (considerably more complex) priority queue operations.

Comment: @anujpradhan the spanning tree generated by Dijkstra is not minimal. However, you _can_ modify Dijkstra to find a MST - then it's called Prim's algorithm or the D[ijkstra-]J[arník-]P[rim's] algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the two main solutions to the minimum spanning tree problem differ in the way the graph is represented. While [Kruskal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm) works well with edge list, [Prim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm)'s algorithm will better work with a neighbourhood list.  If I am left to decide on the graph representation I prefer to implement Kruskal as I find it easier to implement, but the difference is really small in that aspect- so it's up to you.

Comment: First of all thanks for replying....and i m just trying to figure out one example when kruskal is better than prim's or vice-versa..

Comment: @anujpradhan if you already have the graph stored in an neighbourhood list or in edge list you should prefer Prim or Kruskal respectively.

Comment: @izmorphius suppose i am given a graph and not any other info then we can't suppose to have a sorted list of edges,neighbours...then which?

Comment: I use Kruskal because I implement it faster, but probably people that will tell you to choose Prim.